# How is exponentiation defined?

Tags: definition, exponentiation

Here is how I think this work:

We define

$ a^b = \underbrace {a\cdots a}_b $ for $a \in R $ and $b \in N$.

Since so far we have not defined what $ a^{-1}$ is, $a^{-4}$ makes no sense. (right?) We can define $a^{-1}$ however we want but to preserve property $a^{m+n} = a^m\cdots a^n$ we **choose**  $a^{-1} = \frac{1}{a}$. To define $a^b$ over whole set of integers we need to define $a^0$, and we **choose** it to be $1$. In other words

$$ a^b = \underbrace {a\cdots a}_{b} \text{ for }b>0$$

$$ a^b = 1 \text{ for }b=0$$

$$ a^b = \underbrace {\frac{1}{a}\cdots\frac{1}{a}}_{-b} \text{ for }b < 0$$ where $a \in R \text{ and } b \in Z$

Now $b$ can be any integer but $a^\frac{1}{b}, b  \in N $ is stil undefined and we have to **choose** what $a^\frac{1}{b}$ will be. And we **choose** it to be $\sqrt[b]{a}$. Expanded definition would look something like

$$b=\frac{c}{d}, c \in Z, d \in N $$

$$ a^b = \underbrace {a\cdots a}_{b} \text{ for } c \mod d =0 \text{ and } b>0$$

$$ a^b = 1 \text{ for }b=0$$

$$ a^b = \underbrace {\frac{1}{a}\cdots \frac{1}{a}}_{-b} \text{ for } c \mod d =0 \text{ and } b < 0$$

$$ a^b = \underbrace {\sqrt[d]{a} \cdots\sqrt[d]{a}}_c \text{ for } c \mod d \neq 0  $$

To further expand definition we have to use $e$ and calculus.

So is this correct, and do we really simply **choose** values for $a^{-1}$, $a^\frac{1}{b}$ and $a^0$ just because they fit nicely (and make life easier) or for some other reason?

Comment: at first we define $a^{p/q} = (\sqrt[q]{a})^p$ for $a \in ]0;\infty[$ and $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$. then this is extended to $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ and finally to $x \in \mathbb{R}$ where $x = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{p_n}{q_n}$ and $a^x = \lim_{n \to \infty} a^{p_n/q_n}$

Comment: That's how I understand it. First we define $ a^n $ for positive integers $ n$. Then we define $ a^0$ so that $ a^0 a^1 = a^{0+1} $. Then we define $ a^{-n} $ for positive integers $ n $ so that $ a^{-n} a^n = a^{-n+n} $, etc. Note that if $ a> 0$ we can define $ a^x =\sup \{a^q : q < x, q \text { rational}\} $.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is my understanding of the subject as well. Note that the moment the exponent stops being an integer, you need to restrict the base to non-negative real numbers, because you want $a^{3}$ and $a^{6/2}$ to be equal (and the last one to make sense at all).

I personally prefer extending to real exponents by requiring the function $x\mapsto a^x$ to be continuous, but you get the same result in the end, so it matters little.